# Using command prompt batch files to move and automatically rename duplicate files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rename, move

So, here's what I have: I created a small batch file to record the results of a ping test to a text file.  What I want to do is run the batch file and move the results log to a specific folder on the Desktop automatically.  Then, if the target filename exists, automatically rename accordingly.  Meaning, if File1 exists, create File2, File3, so on and so forth.  Here's what I have so far:

```
@echo off
color A
title Ping Test
:A
echo.
cls
ping google.com -n 4 > C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\pingresults.txt
cls
:Question
echo.
echo You can find the results in C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\pingresults.txt
echo Would you like to run this test again? (Y/N)
Set /p Choice=
if %choice% equ y goto :A
if %choice% equ n goto :Results
if %choice% neq y goto :Question
if %choice% neq n goto :Question
:Results
cls
echo Would you like to view the results of the test? (Y/N)
Set /p Choice=
if %choice% equ y goto :OpenResults
if %choice% equ n goto :Close
if %choice% neq y goto :Results
if %choice% neq n goto :Results
:Close
exit
:OpenResults
start C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\pingresults.txt
```

And the move batch file looks like this:

```
@echo off
echo.
cd C:\Users\Diesel\Desktop
move pingresults.txt PingResults\
if exist pingresults.txt ren pingresults.txt=+1
Exit.
```

I don't want to overwrite the existing file, but rename it in succession.  I can't find any helpful articles anywhere using only batch files, they all say to use vbs or php, a language I'm not familiar with

Answer (score 3):

To rename files to `file1 [file2][...]` and move it in a desktop folder:

```
@ECHO Off &SETLOCAL
FOR %%a IN (*.txt) DO CALL:processFile "%%~a"
goto:eof

:processFile
SETLOCAL
:loop
SET /a fileCounter+=1
SET "fileName=%~n1%filecounter%%~x1"
IF EXIST "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%fileName%" GOTO:loop
ECHO MOVE "%~1" "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%fileName%"
ENDLOCAL
goto:eof
```

Look at the output and remove the word `echo` before `move`  if it looks good.

Comment: Makes sense to me, and it should work the way I need it, but here's my question:

Let's say the name of the file I need to move is called "Test".  Where in this code would I substitute "fileName" for "Test"?

Answer (score 0):

I have a pair of utility files that do this, so I can call from either command line, or another batch file.  This manages several versions of the file in the same folder, and I would call it *before* moving your new file in.

Usage is:

```
archivefile 5 "c:\temp\songs" .txt [move]
```

Where 5 is the number of versions to keep.
The base file name in this example is "`c:\temp\songs.txt`"
and it creates (in `c:\temp`) 5 files: `songs_1.txt songs_2.txt songs_3.txt songs_4.txt songs_5.txt`

If you specify `move` it will move the original `songs.txt` otherwise it copies it.

Note, if you're using it from another batch file (which you'll probably want to), you need to use `call` or it won't return to your original batch file (both batch files will exit instead, which isn't what you want):

```
call archivefile 5 "c:\temp\songs" .txt
```

You need the pair of batch files to be either in the current directory, or on the windows path.  Now I think about it, archivefile_b.bat could probably be a sub-routine within the main file instead, but it ain't broke, so I'm not going to fix it.

This is archivefile.bat:

```
@Echo off 
rem archivefile.bat - keep a number of archives of a file
rem paramters:  n rootfile extension [move|copy]
rem n = number of files to keep.
rem move|copy optional indicator to rename (move) the original file instead of copying it
rem archivefile 5 "c:\temp\songs" .txt [move]
rem 




if "%3"=="" goto usage

set _af_n=%1
set _af_root=%2
set _af_ext=%3

set _af_move=copy
set _af_moveX=%4
if "%_af_moveX%"=="move" set _af_move=move

set _af_i=
set _af_j=

rem make sure that the first parameter (n) is numeric
set /A _af_n=%_af_n%
if "%_af_n%"=="0" echo Error: number of copies must be numeric (%1) & goto usage

if not exist %_af_root%%_af_ext% echo Error: cannot locate main file: %_af_root%%_af_ext% & goto error


rem remove the oldest file
if exist %_af_root%_%_af_n%%_af_ext% del %_af_root%_%_af_n%%_af_ext%

rem move up the remainder
for /L %%i in (%_af_n%, -1, 1) do call archivefile_b %%i %_af_root% %_af_ext% 

rem copy the original

if "%_af_move%"=="move" goto moveIt
rem move not specified - make a copy
copy %_af_root%%_af_ext% %_af_root%_1%_af_ext%

goto moveCopyDone

:moveIt

rem need filename only for a rename
set _af_destfile=%_af_root%_1%_af_ext%
set _af_destfile=%_af_destfile:"=%
for %%i in (%_af_destfile%) do set _af_destfile=%%~ni%%~xi

ren %_af_root%%_af_ext% %_af_destfile%



:moveCopyDone



dir %_af_root%*%_af_ext%


goto done

:usage
echo usage: archivefile n rootfile extension
echo   - n = number of archives to keep
echo   - rootfile = the root filename
echo   - extension = file extension
echo.
echo example:
echo archivefile 5 "c:\Documents and Settings\gregh\My Documents\Rescued document" .txt 
goto done

:error
rem could maybe do something here? naa.
goto done

:done
```

This is archivefile_b.bat, which manages just one of the files:

```
rem @Echo off 
rem archivefile_b.bat - helper for the archivefile routine
rem  -- juggles ONE of the archive files.

rem paramters:  n rootfile extension
rem n = the index to move from n to n+1
rem archivefile 5 "c:\temp\songs" .txt
rem therefore renames c:\temp\songs_5.txt to c:\temp\songs_6.txt


set _afb_n=%1
set _afb_root=%2
set _afb_ext=%3


rem make sure that the first parameter (n) is numeric
set /A _afb_n=%_afb_n%
if "%_afb_n%"=="0" echo Error: (archivefile_b) number of copies must be numeric (%1) & goto done

set /A _afb_j=%_afb_n%+1

rem define the file names
set _afb_fn=%_afb_root%_%_afb_n%%_afb_ext%
set _afb_fj=%_afb_root%_%_afb_j%%_afb_ext%

rem remove the quotes
set _afb_fn=%_afb_fn:"=%
set _afb_fj=%_afb_fj:"=%

rem can only supply a filename to the ren command (not path)
for %%i in (%_afb_fj%) do set _afb_fj=%%~ni%%~xi

rem do the rename now
if exist "%_afb_fn%" ren "%_afb_fn%" "%_afb_fj%" 


:done
```